# Getting mouse coordinates relative to target control in drag/drop operations

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I see how to get the coordinates of the mouse relative to the entire screen when doing Drag & Drop events, but I'm a bit unclear on the best way to get the mouse coordinates relative to the control the drop occurs in.  Do I have to calculate it based on the controls position in the form and the form's position in the screen or is there a more straightforward way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Control.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
yourTargetControl.PointToClient(screenPoint);
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something easy.  Thanks :)